# Rails: How to get enum value for joined table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two models with `enum` fields:

```
class TempAsset < ApplicationRecord
  enum state: { running: 0, stopped: 1, terminated: 2 }
end

class AssetCredential < ApplicationRecord
  enum map_status: { pending: 0, inprogress: 1, passed: 2, failed: 3 }
end
```

When I select column from the first table, it gives proper values from enum:

```
TempAsset
  .joins('INNER JOIN asset_credentials
          ON temp_assets.instance_id = asset_credentials.instance_id')
  .pluck(:state)
  .uniq
# ["stopped", "running"]
```

But, it gives numbers when I select column from the joined table:

```
TempAsset
  .joins('INNER JOIN asset_credentials
          ON temp_assets.instance_id = asset_credentials.instance_id')
  .pluck(:map_status)
  .uniq
# [0, 3, 2, 1]
```

So, should I do something like this:

```
AssetCredential.map_statuses.key(0) => "pending"
AssetCredential.map_statuses.key(1) => "inprogress"
```

Or is there any better way to do the same?

Comment: Can you please specify the relation between AssetCredential and TempAsset? Is it many to many or one to many?

Comment: if you are only interested in `map_status` column and Activerecord knows how to map the enums to string for base table, you can use `AssetCredential ` as a Base table for join

Answer (score 2):

`ActiveRecord::Enum` is not designed to work across `join table`, therefore you cannot select or pluck other table enum column and expect the mapping value in return. As you said what you can do is to pluck the integer value and do the mapping by yourself.

Or in my case, I use [enumerize](https://github.com/brainspec/enumerize) gem which stores values in the database and gives you more options and customization such as validation and I18n. With this gem you can use your code above to pluck the expected values (because it stores exact value not mapping with integer).

Answer (score 1):

```
TempAsset
  .joins('
    JOIN asset_credentials
    ON temp_assets.instance_id = asset_credentials.instance_id
  ')
  .where(
    state: TempAsset.states[:terminated],
    asset_credentials: { map_status: AssetCredentials.map_statuses[:passed] }
  )
```

You can change the keys being passed in to whatever you need. I'm not sure what model you want returned but your could switch things around to suit your needs

Answer (score 1):

Given the rails associations are setup, can also try something like:

```
TempAsset
  .joins('join asset_credentials on temp_assets.instance_id = asset_credentials.instance_id')
  .map { |temp_asset| [temp_asset| [temp_asset.asset_credential.map_status] }
  .uniq
```

Answer (score 0):

See, the problem here is you are using `active-record` enums. These are stored as integers in the database, and mapping to some text is done on the application level. `pluck` works on the db level.

Whats happening here is when you do a `inner join`, it is collection columns from both tables. When you pluck from the table which you are joining-from, active record knows how to map it to the enum. In the second one, you are plucking column from another table, and active-record is unable to get the context.

Here, you can try using `postgres` enums for proper results.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to simulate your problem. The interesting thing which I found here was this issue does not arise when we use 'joins' on 'one-to-many' relationship.

i.e., if one 'TempAsset' has many 'AssetCredentials', the query
`TempAsset.joins(:asset_credentials)` 
gives out enum values as you expect. Whereas
`AssetCredential.joins(:temp_asset)` does produce the issue which you have mentioned.

So, If you can establish 'has_many' relationship between 'TempAsset' and 'AssetCredentials' through a 'has_one' relationship between 'TempAsset' and 'Instance', the issue could get fixed.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
AssetCredential.joins('INNER JOIN temp_assets ON asset_credentials.instance_id = temp_assets.instance_id').pluck(:map_status).uniq
```

Comment: Actually I need both the columns of enum type

Comment: What do you mean with "both columns"? Do you mean the cartesian product?